# Is it bad practice to call scripts from a users home dir from root tasks (eg. dhcp hooks)?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, security

I have some small script that run at startup and on other events (for example, one that updates a dynamic dns hostname based on the machines IP changing). I would like to keep everything in my home dir (`/home/danny`) so that they're all in one place (ultimately they will be in a repo I'll clone into my home dir) rather than scattered around the filesystem.

Is it bad practice to create a DHCP hook that calls scripts from here directly (`/home/danny/scripts/update_dyndns`)?

Note: It's a Raspberry Pi, where I am the sole user. There's no concern about the user replacing this script to do something else (this used is on the sudoer list, so if the danny account is compromised, the whole install is anyway).

Comment: Go the route with the repo so that the system and you will find everything where you look for it...

Answer (score 1):

This question is primarily opinion, but I'll go ahead and give you mine. In this case, I don't think it could be considered "bad practice", but in a larger (i.e. corporate) environment, it probably would be. On an RPi at home, go for it - if it were a corporate server that I were a co-admin on, I'd have to object to doing so.

Answer (score 1):

If you call a user script in the users home (editable by the user) with root permissions, that effectively means the user is root. From a security / principle of least privilege point of view, that's a very bad thing to do.

Of course, in your case it might not matter. As long as you know what you are doing and what the possible repercussions are, and if you don't let it become a habit so might do it later without thinking about it...

Personally I just put the update dyndns stuff in root land, not sure why that would require giving regular users root. Even if you are the only user, not using the root account when you don't need to is also a measure to prevent accidents.